# How to indent multi line comment of c in vim

Tags: c, vim

I write multi line comment properly indented before every function I write in c code in the project I am working. I use gvim editor. Problem is many a times I make some changes in the function and have to re edit the comment, and reediting the comment makes the comment un indented. I again have to reindent the comment. I find it difficult to reedit the multi line comment. Is there any shortcut or utility in gvim using which I can easily indent multi line comment automatically?

I searched in net about this problem and could not find anything useful to solve this problem.  Here I am showing an example of multi line comment that I wrote before a function followed by the multi line comment after reediting(note it is now un indented) it followed by expected result.

I also have another question. Do you write comment before every function you write in c. If yes how to maintain the indentation of the comment if you make some changes in the function?

```
/*
 * Function: remove_item_from_list
 * --------------------
 *  Removes an item from a list. Here list is a sequence of same type objects. 
 *  pItem is also same type object. This is a generic function in the sense
 *  that it can work for different type of objects. Currently pList will have 
 *  only one copy of pItem w.r.t. the calling places. So whenever the item  
 *  found a break statement is used.
 *
 *  pList : a sequence of objects
 *  pItem : object
 *
 *  returns: modified list
 */
```

Now I reedited the comment after making some changes int the function. Now the comment in gvim editor looks like as follows. My changes in the comment are present within ## ## block.

```
/*
 * Function: remove_item_from_list
 * --------------------
 *  Removes an item from a list. Here list is a sequence of same type objects. 
 *  pItem is also same type object. This is a generic function in the sense
 *  that it can work for different type of objects. ##Currently it works for Animal and Bird type objects. If you want this function to work for some there type object then you have add check for that object. Note that this function assumes that pItem can't be NULL.## Currently pList will have 
 *  only one copy of pItem w.r.t. the calling places. So whenever the item  
 *  found a break statement is used.
 *
 *  pList : a sequence of objects
 *  pItem : object
 *
 *  returns: modified list
 */
```

```
/*
 * Function: remove_item_from_list
 * --------------------
 *  Removes an item from a list. Here list is a sequence of same type objects. 
 *  pItem is also same type object. This is a generic function in the sense
 *  that it can work for different type of objects. Currently it works for 
 *  Animal and Bird type objects. If you want this function to work for some 
 *  there type object then you have add check for that object. Note that this 
 *  function assumes that pItem can't be NULL.## Currently pList will have 
 *  only one copy of pItem w.r.t. the calling places. So whenever the item  
 *  found a break statement is used.
 *
 *  pList : a sequence of objects
 *  pItem : object
 *
 *  returns: modified list
 */
```

Comment: The term is not "indent", indent means the leading whitespace. What you want is text wrapping. See `:help textwidth` for some info on this, and check if `formatoptions` contains `c` flag. (and of course, `:help formatoptions` too).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `gq` command (`:help gq`). Run a visual selection around the paragraph to format and type `gq`. Based on the set `textwidth` (as mentioned @Michail), Vim will wrap the text properly, keeping in mind that it's a comment.

In this way, you can type your comment, edit it, come back to it, without caring much of the formatting, and formatting once you are happy with it.

Comment: The suggestion you gave perfectly solves my problem, thanks a lot. Now I will be free from the pain.

Comment: `gq` also takes a motion, so `gqip` will reformat the whole paragraph. See `:h motion.txt`.

Comment: Great @Ranju, if you are happy with it, don't forget to approve the response :-)